# how do i check load on a xen host

Tags: virtualization, xen

I have just started to play ariund with xen virtualization. I want to know stuff like how high the load is on the host system, how can i rind out this sort of information from when logged in to the dom0

Answer (score 2):

Try `xm top` and other `xm` [commands](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xm) as `xm list`.

Comment: or xl top if you're using the new xl toolstack.  It actually just calls xentop though.

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of virt-manager give you a sum of all loads as the load of the Dom0.
What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: I dont think i can use virt manager, i do not have any gui installed on the host. it is a pretty clean debian install. What i want to find out primarily is how much cpu is used. Running htop on the host machine would do.

Comment: htop and top will only show the load of the Dom0 system. This is propably not what you want, since your running DomUs add to the load on your real CPUs. So do you want to see the total load on your real cpus or just the Dom0 load of its virtual cpus?

Comment: I want to se the total load of my real cpus

Comment: then maybe top is what you're after?

Comment: @Matt propably `xentop`. But is seems like Joelbitar has lost the interest in his own question.

Answer (score 0):

`xentop` and `xenmon.py` are good tools for a general view